# How to assign a value of variable as name of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I pass a string through "objName".

I want this to to be stored in the line: facebookData.objName

For example:

if I invoke the function like, **fetchData(0, response, "friendsCount")**, the object should be like: **facebookData.friendsCount** = dLen;

Note: facebookData is a global object.

```
             function fetchData(dLen, response, objName){

                if(response.paging){

                    if(!response.paging.next){

                        facebookData.objName = dLen; //Problem is here
                        return dLen;
                    }
                    else{
                        -------------------
                       fetchData(dLen, response, objName);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You should use bracket notation: `facebookData[objName] = dLen;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use brackets:

```
facebookData[objName] = dLen;
```